# Laravel collection->push() not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I want to collect product and push to the session cart.

```
$product= Product::find(1);
$product2= Product::find(2);

session(['cart' => collect($product)]);

session(['cart' => session('cart')->push($product2)])
```

This is my output with some dummy data.

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 2,
    "sku": "SKU914",
    "price": 1.0,
    "special_price": 0.91,
    "weight": 763,
    "barcode": "0434120288572",
    "created_at": "2020-01-31 14:39:53",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-31 14:39:53"
  },
  "id": 1,
  "sku": "SKU579",
  "price": 22.8,
  "special_price": 19.14,
  "weight": 478459,
  "barcode": "1390377688",
  "created_at": "2020-01-31 14:34:59",
  "updated_at": "2020-01-31 14:34:59"
}
```

The second product ($product2) which I pushed become outside of the array.
How should I do to make it like `"0": {}, "1": {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place $product in an array.

```
session(['cart' => collect([$product])]);
session(['cart' => session('cart')->push($product2)]);
```

Or just push

```
session(['cart' => session('cart')->push($product)]);
session(['cart' => session('cart')->push($product2)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your request simply use like this

```
session(['cart' => collect($product)]);

$card1[] = session('cart');
$card1[] = collect($product1);
session(['cart' => $card1])

$card2[] = session('cart');
$card2[] = collect($product2);
session(['cart' => $card2])
```

or you can use **whereIn()**

```
$products = Product::whereIn("id",[1,2])->get()->toArray();
session(['cart' => $products])
```

or can use **array_merge**

```
session(['cart' => collect($product)]);

$cart = array_merge(session('cart'),collect($product2));
session(['cart' => $cart])
```

Comment: I want to use it separately, because the product is add one-by-one by user

Comment: did u checked array_merge ??

Comment: array_merge cannot use with the collect method

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to merge anything

2 query will be slow so better to run only one query

```php
$Ids = [1,2];
if(true) { // can add any condtion here
   array_push(3); // if you need to push new id
}
$product= Product::whereIn("id",$Ids)->get();
session(['cart' => $product]);
```

you can apply `whereIn()` condition

Comment: you don't need to use the `collect`, it is already a collection.

Comment: and change `where` to `whereIn`

Comment: I want to use it separately, because the product is add one-by-one by user

Comment: @BlackLotus now check you can push as many id you want but SQL query will be single and fast